# SQL Server Schema Output

Tags: sql-server, schema, diagram

How do I output the schema of my database?  I want it to output the design of the database.

Something like this might work:

```
 SELECT TABLE_TYPE, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 ORDER BY TABLE_TYPE, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
```

But I can't get it to run correctly.  A excel file with table names, their columns, types, primary keys, etc. is what I want.

Comment: okay i added more notes above

Comment: sql server management studio 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

... sounds like what you are looking for, sans any formatting you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
t.type_desc,
t.name as [table], 
c.name as [column],
y.name,
c.max_length
from sys.tables t inner join
sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id inner join
sys.types y on c.system_type_id = y.system_type_id
where y.name <> 'sysname'
order by 
t.type_desc,
t.name, 
c.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Below posts would be useful for generating data dictionary

Database Documentation - http://deepakrangarajan.blogspot.com/2011/03/database-documentation.html

Generating a Database Data Dictionary - http://sqlserverdiaries.com/blog/index.php/2011/02/generating-a-database-data-dictionary/